# Would AzureDistributionBundle play well with AsseticBundle?

Tags: symfony, azure, azure-web-roles

I'm very much interested in getting my hands dirty to run Symfony2 Application on Windows Azure. I've tried but no luck. Recently I found the AzureDistributionBundle that would automatically configure Symfony2 to play well with Windows Azure.

But I'm skeptic, would it play well if I'll be using it with Assetic, with Lesscss, yuicompressor etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the packaging process is configured to serve assets (such as images, stylesheets, javascript) from the local webserver, your answer is **YES**. If you configure your Azure Blob Storage Account you can change this to automatically deploy to Azure Blob.

This offers much better performance (CDN) for your assets and much better conditions for traffic.

To use Azure Blog storage add the following configuration to your config.yml:

```
windows_azure_distribution:
    assets:
        type: blob
        accountName: acc
        accountKey: pw1
```

During packaging the Azure Distribution bundle will copy all assets onto Azure Blob storage, versioned by the current build number. This way different assets between different versions in staging/production will never affect each other.

Make sure to clean up your storage account and delete those old version containers if you don’t need them anymore.

More information can be found at: http://beberlei.github.com/AzureDistributionBundle/

Comment: Hi Dave, It might seem a dumb question, but to noobs like me would be a great help. So it means that in a cloud service instance, there is a node.js and jre installed?

Comment: What cloud service? ... Normally you have to install Java & nobe.js on your own

Comment: the one with the web/worker role. because you need java to run yui compressor, as well as node.js to run lesscss.js.